# Unable to SELECT two columns using trivially simple query with PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

Below is a complete PHP file with the database schema in comments.

I simply want to select more than one column using PDO. This works:

```
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT `title` from `wishlist` LIMIT 0, 10');
```

This returns an  "Internal Server Error".

```
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT `title`,`comments` from `wishlist` LIMIT 0, 10');
```

Query works fine in phpMyAdmin. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 

/*
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wishlist` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
 `priority` integer NOT NULL,
`comments` text,
`timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
*/

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    try 
    {
        $connection = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mrabcac_test;charset=utf8';
        $dbname='root';
        $password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $db = new PDO($connection, $dbname,$password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Works fine
        $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT `title` from `wishlist` LIMIT 0, 10');
        // Results in "Internal Server Error"
        $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT `title`,`comments` from `wishlist` LIMIT 0, 10');
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo(json_encode($result));
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex ) 
    {
        echo "Database error: ". $ex->getMessage();
    } 

?>
```

Comment: What happens when you comment out the first prepare statement?

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, look in your web server's error log where the error will be detailed. Always develop code with `display_errors` turned on:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: It shouldn't be a PDO error because the `try/catch` block would catch it. Something else is going on...

Comment: How long can the `comments` field be?

Comment: @Shomz, it still returns the internal error when I comment out the first prepare statement.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, the error log says only this:

    [Sun Aug 24 21:53:13 2014] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/[my user name]/public_html/index.php

There is no index.php mentioned in my file; all the code in the file is shown above.

Comment: @tomcam Forget the log then (`log_errors` may be off), make sure you have the two configs I suggested earlier at the top of this script, then run it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you very much for sticking with this. I did put those two configs at the top of the script. Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place for errors? I'm using the CPanel error log. The missing index.php error is still appearing but nothing else. I am beginning to think there's something wrong with my shared host config. The .cnf file is supposed to be in /etc... but I can't seem to find a /etc directory :-O

Comment: With `display_errors` turned on, they should show right there in your browser - comment out the two `header()` calls so the browser doesn't try anything to handle JSON and see if your error shows on screen. And if you were doing this as an AJAX call before, hit the URL directly, plus inspect the actual response in your browser's Network console.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, all. It turned out to be some kind of misconfiguration. When I tried it on a couple of other hosts everything worked just fine. It appears I am not yet senile.